# ASP.NET (VB) Extension Method not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, extension-methods, asp.net-4.0

I have the following Extension Method

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Namespace Extensions
    Public Module IntegerExtensions

        <Extension()>
        Public Function ToCommaDeliminatedNumber(ByVal int As Integer) As String

            Dim _input As String = int.ToString
            Select Case int
                Case Is > 99999 : Return _input.Remove(_input.Length - 3) & "k"
                Case Is > 9999 : Return Math.Round(Double.Parse(int / 1000), 1).ToString & "k"
                Case Is > 999 : Return String.Format("{0:N0}", int)
                Case Else : Return _input
            End Select

        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

And in one of my classes I'm using

```
user.Reputation.ToCommaDeliminatedNumber
```

I am importing the Extensions Namespace into the Class, but the error I'm getting is...

> 'ToCommaDeliminatedNumber' is not a member of 'Integer?'.

Can anybody tell me what I might be missing here?  I do have other Extension Methods for Strings and Dates that work exactly as expected... I'm just at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your error message it looks like `user.Reputation` is actually a `Nullable(Of Integer)`, based on the trailing question mark ('Integer?'). Is that correct?

Your extension method is extending `Integer`, not `Integer?` (i.e., `Nullable(Of Integer)`), hence the error. So either provide an overload that handles `Integer?` or call `Value` on the nullable type:

```
user.Reputation.Value.ToCommaDeliminatedNumber()
```

You will need to check that it is not null (`Nothing`) otherwise an exception will be thrown. An overloaded method might look like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToCommaDeliminatedNumber(ByVal int As Integer?) As String

    Return int.GetValueOrDefault().ToCommaDeliminatedNumber()

End Function
```

In the case that it's null the default value of 0 would be displayed.

Comment: D'ur - Thanks for the second pair of eyes.  The nullable integer was exactly the problem.